# How to dockerize an NX cypress e2e application

Tags: angular, docker, cypress, nrwl-nx

I've an NX workspace containing only one angular app and its e2e app, which is using cypress.

I'm trying to create a docker image for the e2e testing, but it fails when I run the docker container.
This is my `Dockerfile` which lives now in the root folder in the workspace.

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /app/package.json
COPY decorate-angular-cli.js /app/decorate-angular-cli.js
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
RUN npm install reflect-metadata tslib
# add cypress dependencies for image build 
RUN apk add xauth xvfb

# add app
COPY . /app
CMD npm run e2e -- --headless
```

The image is built but when I run the container I'm getting cypress dependencies error.

```
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files | Names         |      Size
vendor.js           | vendor        |  11.33 MB
styles.css          | styles        | 685.68 kB
polyfills.js        | polyfills     | 128.53 kB
main.js             | main          | 118.15 kB
runtime.js          | runtime       |   6.61 kB

| Initial Total |  12.25 MB

Build at: 2021-09-20T15:27:50.264Z - Hash: 8cbcb444b6a50b421afd - Time: 86112ms

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


✔ Compiled successfully.
It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 7.7.0

[STARTED] Task without title.
[FAILED] Cypress failed to start.
[FAILED]
[FAILED] This may be due to a missing library or dependency. https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies
[FAILED]
[FAILED] Please refer to the error below for more details.
[FAILED]
[FAILED] ----------
[FAILED]
[FAILED] Command failed with ENOENT: /root/.cache/Cypress/7.7.0/Cypress/Cypress --no-sandbox --smoke-test --ping=690
[FAILED] spawn /root/.cache/Cypress/7.7.0/Cypress/Cypress ENOENT
[FAILED]
[FAILED] ----------
[FAILED]
[FAILED] Platform: linux (Alpine Linux - 3.11.12)
[FAILED] Cypress Version: 7.7.0
Cypress failed to start.

This may be due to a missing library or dependency. https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies

Please refer to the error below for more details.

----------

Command failed with ENOENT: /root/.cache/Cypress/7.7.0/Cypress/Cypress --no-sandbox --smoke-test --ping=690
spawn /root/.cache/Cypress/7.7.0/Cypress/Cypress ENOENT

----------

Platform: linux (Alpine Linux - 3.11.12)
Cypress Version: 7.7.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! icert@2.0.0 e2e: `ng e2e "--headless"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the icert@2.0.0 e2e script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-09-20T15_27_51_378Z-debug.log
```

I need to know if this is the right way for dockerizing e2e apps with `Nx` and if so then what I'm missing here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Cypress isn't supported on Alpine Linux yet (or may never be). I advice you to instead use one of the [officially supported Cypress Docker images](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images). Even if you manage to make Cypress run on Alpine, it will require downloading lots of external dependencies to build Chrome/Electron, which will make the disk size optimizations negligible.

Comment: okay! But I'm getting so many errors when using docker images in my Nx workspace since I have cypress for each app individually. Do you have any resources that can help me?